# Cans someone explain where the static variable comes from? ::MEDIA

Tags: magento2

Forgive me for my naivete but I'm modifying a custom extension and I see this variable:

```
$mediaPath = $fileSystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath();
```

I went through **Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList** but can't find any mention of `::MEDIA`. Can someone please clue me in? Thank you! I'm new to M2.

Answer (score 1):

It's there - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/67ee5ff13590936a320bfa6126181a091cb0005a/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php#L48 - you're looking for the *class constant* defined as `const MEDIA = 'media';`

Though the path most likely will not be the same as in the git, it's probably `vendor/magento/framework/App/Filesystem/DirectoryList.php` for you.

See also https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php